# Sandbox: Knox connection refused

Tags: hbase, ambari, ssh-tunnel, hortonworks-sandbox, knox-gateway

I am using the Hortonworks Sandbox and have a problem connecting to HBase via ssh tunneling. It actually worked before, but after a restart of the server something must have been changed without my knowledge.

Currently the connection is always refused with the error message:

> ERROR hadoop.gateway (KnoxLdapRealm.java:doGetAuthenticationInfo(198))
>   - Shiro unable to login: javax.naming.CommunicationException: ***:33389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]

This error occurs, eg., after executing `curl -ku admin:admin-password 'https://localhost:8443/gateway/default/hbase'`. I therefore suppose that Knox is badly configured. However, Ambari and its services seem to run fine, there are no other error messages. I have tried restarting all services serval times without success.

Could anybody give me any hint where I could look for the problem? I have already tried the debugging tips from [here](http://kminder.github.io/knox/2015/11/18/setting-up-knox.html) (`jps`, `lsof`) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Demo LDAP that is shipped with Knox (it uses port 33389). It might be down, to start it go to Knox Configuration page of Ambari and from there start the Demo LDAP server.